# I'm looking for some guidance in a project using Tone.js making a drum sequencer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tone.js

I'm a student and working on a project for my course. I decided to try and make a drum sequencer using JS, react and tone.js. I have got to a point where I have a grid of buttons that can be toggled and I have a play and stop button. By console logging I can see that when I press play it is stepping through the grid and it is registering buttons as either active or not active. But I can't seem to get the sounds from tone sampler into the squares on the grid. I wonder if anyone can see where I'm going wrong? https://gist.github.com/cseath88/0fb298929915589b833a5015db9e2229

I've tried many things, I tried using a tone.js synth instead to see if I could get that to pass the notes to my grid but had no luck with that either.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please remember to take the [tour] and read up on what's [on-topic](/help/on-topic) here, and then also make sure to read the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) when you think you have something that is a good question for SO. Right now, your post does not talk about a _specific_ problem with [mcve] code that shows that problem happening, and a description of specific things you already tried in terms of (re)searching and debugging. So please either [edit] your post, or it might be too early to ask here. Either way: show your code, posts should be self-contained.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).